# Lower-bound for three-color Ramsey Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, upper-lower-bounds, ramsey-theory, probabilistic-method

I am trying to find a lower-bound for `R(k,k,k)` , which is defined as `"the smallest N such that every red/blue/green coloring of the pairs in` $N\choose 2$ `contains some set of k elements where every pair receives the same color."`

I want to use the Erdos method that is used in proving the 2-color version, but I am not sure where to start. Any helps?

Comment: What is the Erdös method you're referring too?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you check these slides, starting from page 10? http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dmmr/slides/ramsey-Ch7.pdf

Comment: I presume it's the probabilistic method (e.g., in these notes: http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture06.pdf). So, in fact, one doesn't find a specific graph $G$, but rather just proves that the probability such a $G$ exists is nonzero.

Comment: It looks like if you just go through Theorem 1 of those notes, with $n=3^{s/2}$, then the same proof works to show that $R(s,s,s)>3^{s/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

To find a lower bound you need a specific graph $G$ and colouring by three colours than has **no** monochrome $k$-clique. Then you have shown that $R(k,k,k) > |V(G)|$. Presumably you need to find a family of graphs parametrised in $k$..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the probabilistic method you have that $P(c(\{v_i, v_j\})=k) = \frac13$ for each edge $\{v_i, v_j\}$ of the graph and $c: V \to \{r,b,g\}$ is a colouring and each $k \in \{r,b,g\}$. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ many $k$-cliques and the probability that a given one of them is monochrome is $3 \cdot \frac{1}{3^{\binom{k}{2}}}$ by the previous (times 3 for the three colours), and we have $\binom{k}{2}$ pairs of edges that independently all must have the same colour.

So we get that there is at least one such clique as upperbounded by $$u(n,k):=\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{3^{\binom{k}{2}-1}}$$ as in page 11 of ["your" slides](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dmmr/slides/ramsey-Ch7.pdf), which I take as a model.

Now ask yourself for what small values of $n$ we have that $u(n,k) < 1$, which ensures that the complementary event has positive probability, which will correspond to graphs/colourings as hinted in my other answer ?